# C random() & setstate function not behaving as expected

Tags: c, random, bsd

I am unsure why these two blocks of code give different outputs:

```
unsigned int seed1 = 0;
char state1[256];
initstate(seed1, state1, 256);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
printf("%10ld\n", random());
// Gives:
// 1216130483
// 1950449197
```

vs.

```
unsigned int seed1 = 0;
char state1[256];
initstate(seed1, state1, 256);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
setstate(state1);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
// Gives:
// 1216130483
// 625602885
```

Am I misunderstanding what setstate() does?

EDIT:
Interestingly enough, look at what this gives:

```
unsigned int seed1 = 0;
char state1[256];
initstate(seed1, state1, 256);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
setstate(state1);
setstate(state1);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
// Gives:
// 1216130483
// 1950449197
```

Comment: C only has `rand` and `srand` and neither `random`, `initstate` or `setstate`. Please tag your question with your OS.

Comment: @JensGustedt I added the bsd tag.

Comment: Running this example on Debian (stable) using `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5` I get the same two numbers for all three code snippts.

Comment: so it looks like this is a bug/incorrect implementation then

Answer (score 3):

Both implementations are correct.

Setstate just changes a static pointer in the routine to point at your buffer.

Initstate is allowed to do the same thing, but is also allowed to alter the buffer contents first.  If the PRNG is something like ARC4 or Spritz, the buffer needs to be a permutation rather than just arbitrary bits.  If the PRNG is a nonlinear additive feedback generator, then at least one of the low bits somewhere in the state needs to be set or it won't work right.  And some libs hash the state buffer so it won't be easy to tell what kind of PRNG is in use just from the seed+output information.  They aren't required to; the lib can do exactly the same thing for initstate and setstate if the generator it's using is an LFSG or something that doesn't require any particular format or have any consistency needs for the buffer.  But if you don't do initstate, and your OS uses something that has such needs, your repeatable sequence may not be as unpredictable as you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the call to `initstate()` doesn't also switch to that state, but the call to `setstate()` does, which is why the latter `random()` call returns a number generated from the new state.

Comment: Having experimented with the code a little, I don't think this is the case. Adding a call to `setstate()` right after `initstate()` makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

The BSD implementation of `setstate` loads auxiliary state information, for error checking purposes, before storing it to the old buffer.  Additionally `initstate` and `setstate` are the only functions that update this information.  This means that when the same buffer is used it [loads stale state](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?annotate=303342#l379), [stores the new data](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?annotate=303342#l388), and [updates the internal state with the former](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?annotate=303342#l394).  Calling `setstate` in this manner repeatedly will alternate the old stored state, and the current internal state, causing the results observed when called twice.

[The comment for `setstate`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?annotate=303342#l366) says that calling it with the current buffer is OK, so either this is the intended behavior, or a [decades old](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/random.c?annotate=1573#l288) bug.

> Note that due to the order in which things are done, it is OK to call
>   setstate() with the same state as the current state.

Answer (score 1):

`initstate()` tells random what buffer to use to store information for
the next random number. You get different answers in calls to `random()` because the information in your buffer `state1[256]` has changed. Look at the output of the following code:

```
#define LEN (32)
void print_hex( char *b)
{
   int i;
   for( i=0; i < LEN; i++) printf("%02x ",((unsigned char *)b)[i]);     
   printf("\n");
}

main()
{
   char state1[256], state2[256], tmp[256];
   initstate( 42, state2, LEN);
   initstate( 62, state1, LEN) ;
   printf("buffer before random():\n");
   print_hex( state1 ) ;
   printf("%10ld\n", random());
   printf("buffer after random():\n");
   print_hex( state1 ) ;

   setstate( state2 ); // Now we are free to copy data from state1
   printf("buffer after setstate():\n");
   print_hex( state1 ) ;
   memcpy( tmp, state1, 256);
   printf("copied to tmp\n");

   setstate( state1 ); // Go on with original sequence
   printf("next random():\n") ;
   printf("%10ld\n", random());
   printf("next random():\n") ;
   printf("%10ld\n", random());

   setstate( state2 ) ; // Again, this allows us to play with data in state1
   memcpy( state1, tmp, 256);
   setstate( state1 ) ;
   printf("back copy:\n");
   printf("random() after copy:\n") ;
   printf("%10ld\n", random());
   printf("next random():\n") ;
   printf("%10ld\n", random());
}
```

This gives the output:

```
buffer before random():
01 00 00 00 e7 22 1d 21 f1 62 9c 90 89 72 b5 89 35 2b 97 b5 76 8c ff a8 56 14 14 7b ba 19 d9 f7
1801070350
buffer after random():
01 00 00 00 e7 22 1d 21 f1 62 9c 90 89 72 b5 89 1c 4e b4 d6 76 8c ff a8 56 14 14 7b ba 19 d9 f7
buffer after setstate():
06 00 00 00 e7 22 1d 21 f1 62 9c 90 89 72 b5 89 1c 4e b4 d6 76 8c ff a8 56 14 14 7b ba 19 d9 f7
copied to tmp
next random():
 483260339
next random():
  40158063
back copy:
random() after copy:
 483260339
next random():
 40158063
```

You can see that after the first call to `random()` the contents of buffer `state1` changes. `random()` uses that area to store its state. This state is copied to buffer `tmp`. Later we copy it back to `state1`, and get the same sequence of random numbers. 
Note that before you copy to or from a buffer that is supposed to be used for random numbers you have to tell `random()` to stop using that buffer using `setstate()` or `initstate()`. The reason is that when `setstate()` is called, the old buffer is modified to allow it to be loaded again with `setstate()`.

So to get the same answer as in the original question, you have to use:

```
unsigned int seed1 = 42;
char state1[256], tmp[256];
initstate(seed1, state1, 256);
printf("%10ld\n", random());
initstate( 0, tmp, 256); // <- notice this
setstate( state1 ) ;
printf("%10ld\n", random());
```